# MojoExecutionException: Maven with Android

Tags: java, android, maven, exception, maven-plugin

I'm using Android Studio with Maven 3.1.1 and in the package goal it crashes with a MojoExecutionException. I have readed lot of posts but I can't get the solution.

**[ERROR] Error when generating sources.**

```
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:593)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:216)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Users\hvalls\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\hvalls\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\res -A C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target\generated-sources\combined-assets\assets -m -J C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target\generated-sources\r --output-text-symbols C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target --auto-add-overlay", Result = -1073741819
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$DefaultCommandExecutor.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:246)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:589)
    ... 28 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 16.665s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Mar 25 22:32:34 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/184M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.8.2:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project my-app: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\Users\hvalls\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\hvalls\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\res -A C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target\generated-sources\combined-assets\assets -m -J C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target\generated-sources\r --output-text-symbols C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target --auto-add-overlay", Result = -1073741819 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.android.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>my-app</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <platform.version>4.1.1.4
        </platform.version>
        <android.plugin.version>3.8.2</android.plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!--Android Annotations-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.androidannotations</groupId>
            <artifactId>androidannotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>${platform.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                    <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${android.plugin.version}</version>
                    <extensions>true</extensions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>19</platform>
                    </sdk>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Solved! I had a @string\ referencing to a non existent in string.xml

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This issue was a little tricky, but can be solved!

First, when you get an error message like the one you got, you should try to run the command which Maven said it failed to run, because after maven downloads dependencies and builds code etc.. Maven it self runs the initial command to make your apk. At your case it is:

```
C:\Users\hvalls\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\build-tools\19.0.3\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I C:\Users\hvalls\AppData\Local\Android\android-studio\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\res -A C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target\generated-sources\combined-assets\assets -m -J C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target\generated-sources\r --output-text-symbols C:\Users\hvalls\Desktop\my-app\target --auto-add-overlay
```

So when you run this it will give you the real error output of the dx.bat tool. Just fix the errors that you see at output and rerun the mvn.

In my case I got this error because one of the image under my res folder is not a png file although the extension is png. After I fixed the file type it worked.

Comment: That is good advice, but it gets a lot trickier when this is the error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'

Comment: could you also show the commands with a more generic sample so it's easier to understand? I have a hard time understanding how I have to alter this in order to make it work for me.

Comment: @PaulGregoire Do you have solution for this situation?

Comment: Sorry @Serob_b its been too long for me to remember

Comment: @PaulGregoire Ok, Thanks for the response ))

Comment: My best advice / opinion is to bite the bullet and use Gradle; Google/Android don't want you to use Maven, so they don't really make it easy anymore.. sad

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error and it costed me 2.5 working days to figure out the problem.
The problem actually is too long pathes on your file system! yes, too long file path!

I moved the project from:

C:\work\workspaces\intelliJ\dory3

to

C:\work\n\dory

and it instantly worked. No errors while building, no problems in IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Error message does not say much, but it means that building your android apk failed. if you look at maven output above error, you might see message with actual error. in my case it was:

```
Extracting libs
Generating R file for Planer:AndroidApk:apk:1.0.0
C:\NetBeansProjects\Planer\AndroidApk\res\values\strings.xml:30: error: Resource entry ui.separator is already defined.
C:\NetBeansProjects\Planer\AndroidApk\res\values\strings.xml:29: Originally defined here.

Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:894)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:323)
...
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command ....
...
```

as you can see information about problem is typed above maven error. Mine problem, for example, was duplication of string resource- for some reason Android studio have made a duplicate. So, you do not have to run that command on your own. just look at the output.