# error occurs while generating apk file using android-maven-plugin

Tags: android-maven-plugin

`I am using android eclipse,i develop a project and add the dependencies GOOGLE play services,
app compact v7 in build path.When i run it as a normal android project it is perfectly executing,I add maven POM.XML file to generate APK file,when i proceed to maven install it gives error.

Error :

[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:608)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:229)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:46)
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "D:\NagarjunaWork\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4.2\aapt.exe package -f --no-crunch -I D:\NagarjunaWork\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -M D:\5-8-2014\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\AndroidManifest.xml -S D:\5-8-2014\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\res -A D:\5-8-2014\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\target\generated-sources\combined-assets -m -J D:\5-8-2014\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\target\generated-sources\r --output-text-symbols D:\5-8-2014\QuickRideApp\QuickRide\target --auto-add-overlay", Result = -1073741819
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$DefaultCommandExecutor.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:252)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:604)
    ... 23 more

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by problems in your XML files, such as referring to a resource ID that no longer exists or never existed. See [MojoExecutionException: Maven with Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646930/mojoexecutionexception-maven-with-android) and [aapt.exe has stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663749/aapt-exe-has-stopped-working) for possible solutions.